# Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS Unable to mount Root is on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, mount

I received a Kernel Panic error after updating Ubuntu server.
After passing the GRUB menu, I received the following error.

I have been hosting a mediawiki on that server that is not backed up.
I do not want to lose that data.

```
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS Unable to mount Root is on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.13.0-62-generic #102~precise1-Ubuntu
Hardware name: Dell Computer Corporation OptiPlex GX260 /OptiPlex GX260  , BIOS A)@ 07/25/2002
00000000 00000000 df437ec8 c16886a4 df437f14 df437eec c167d9da c187a7c4
c1b06c20 00000004 8eafa96c df437f14 fffffffa df72b000 df437f44 c1a0af88
c1868994 df437f14 df437f14 fffffffa 00000000 dfe5f560 c1868358 df72b000
```

I rain boot repair but it did not help
 http://paste.ubuntu.com/12299996/

I tried to apply the fix in from [post 41930](https://askubuntu.com/feeds/question/41930) and had problems.

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 628.7 MiB, 659222528 bytes, 1287544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 18.7 GiB, 20020396032 bytes, 39102336 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000cca65

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048   499711   497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 39100415 38598658 18.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 39100415 38598656 18.4G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/LDPubuntu--vg-root: 17.9 GiB, 19222495232 bytes, 37543936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/LDPubuntu--vg-swap_1: 512 MiB, 536870912 bytes, 1048576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 GiB, 3942645760 bytes, 7700480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1f80e0a4

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 7700479 7698432  3.7G  b W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/zram0: 246.5 MiB, 258420736 bytes, 63091 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Then the problems started...

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount: mount point /mnt/proc does not exist
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount: mount point /mnt/sys does not exist
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run
mount: mount point /mnt/run does not exist
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.19.0-15-generic        3.19.0-15.15                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-15-generic  3.19.0-15.15                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                  3.19.0.15.14                        i386         Generic Linux kernel image
```

What should I try next?